# JAX-RS 2.0 API support to call its clients

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

Most of samples of Jax-rs 2 show how to make a request from a client to the jax-rs application. The client can be a HttpClient, RESTEasy or jax-rs client. I want to know how  jax-rs application can call its clients without client first call to the server.? It is something like pushing into the clients. 
I tried to find over the I'net this, but no supportive source found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is that it is not possible. JAX-RS is working on HTTP transport, which is based on the request-response paradigm. So the client needs to first initiate the connection, then server may send the response to him.

If you want to have two systems which can call each other, then you must implement the services and the clients in both of them:

```
System 1          System 2
Client 1  ------> Service 2
Service 1 <------ Client 2
```

Comment: Thanks swist for your answer. but one more thing. Assume as of your sample, "System 1" is a swing application, and system 2 is a JEE app.Then the jax rs has to be implemented in the swing application to have requests from System 2(jee app) (which is not possible with REST. (RESTFull service in a swing application)  ) ?

Comment: In a case of swing application, I would rather suggests the polling method - repeatedly call the server if it has anything new for you. You may use the asynchronous service (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html), but still it is up to the client to call the server first and through the whole time there is an open connection between server and client.